# Symfony2 form collection — Show only the newest

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form with a Parent (Entity) and Children (Record).
A Parent has many children.
So far so good.

What I need is, that if I edit a Parent I want to show only the newest child as a form collection and not all of them.

Right now with the creation of such I just make it like this:

```
$entity = new WikiEntity();
$record = new WikiRecord();
$entity->addWikiRecord($record);
```

And with this I have just one form collection — obviously.

Now I am looking for a method to have only the newest Record (child) to edit and all of the older one shouldnt be there.

Just to say what my goal is (maybe there are other solutions), I want to create something like a wiki, so everytime the Parent gets edited a new revision gets created, so I can get an older version or something. So the people don't need to see all of the versions (what form collection does) but only the newest one (which will be created each time you edit it).

Comment: you can edit the newest Record without form collection.

Comment: @ihsan it Would be nice if you would also tell me how =)

Comment: I was wrong. Funny that I didn't remember that I've done something more or less similar before. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found an Answer for my problem.

I just manipulate my `getWikiRecords()` function to only return the newest (In the parent function)

So now in the parent Entity for the children it looks like this:

```
public function getWikiRecords() {
    $oneRecord = new ArrayCollection();
    $oneRecord[] = $this->wikiRecords->last();
    return $oneRecord;
}
```

Of course if I want all the Children I now have to use a different get function.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no option to edit only the newest `WikiRecord` on symfony2 form collection type. But it can be done by manipulating form output in template.

So, here is how I could do using twig template.

```
{% for record in edit_form.wikiRecord %}
    {% if loop.length > 1 %}
        {% if loop.last %}
            {{ form_label(record.aFieldName) }}
            {{ form_widget(record.aFieldName) }}
        {% else %}
            {{ form_widget(record.aFieldName, { 'attr': {'style': 'display: none'} }) }}
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_row(record) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I used this for a more or less similar situation where I have to make only the latest children editable. So, this work-around is working. :)

Comment: Okay, this is a beginning. BUT, if you have like 65 Versions (with very much text), then this will become a very long file (even though the user doesn't see it right there) and you can still see it in the source code. Can't I suppress somehow the existence itself in the source code or the unnecessary loading of all the newer ones? This seems to me like it is too much.